# MySql doing multiple counts with different where on the same table for the same user and updating

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck with two things here, that need to be done in a single sql statement.

One, is to do four counts with different where conditions, on the same table, for the same user, and the second part is to update a different table with the data of those counts for the same user.

The whole thing has me in knots. I'm ok with basic `update table select count(*) etc` things, but how is this doable?

**userData**

```
"userId"    "postId"    "postStatus"    "postTitle"
"1"         "1"         "0"             "Title 1"
"1"         "2"         "0"             "Title 2"
"1"         "3"         "0"             "Title 3"
"1"         "4"         "0"             "Title 4"
"1"         "5"         "1"             "Title 5"
"1"         "6"         "1"             "Title 6"
"1"         "7"         "1"             "Title 7"
"1"         "8"         "6"             "Title 8"
"1"         "9"         "5"             "Title 9"
"1"         "10"        "5"             "Title 10"
"2"         "11"        "0"             "Title 11"
"2"         "12"        "0"             "Title 12"
"2"         "13"        "0"             "Title 13"
"2"         "14"        "1"             "Title 14"
```

**userStats**

```
"userId"    "published" "inactive"  "recalled"  "deleted"
"1"         "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"
```

**My failed sql**

```
update userStats set 
published = select count (postStatus) published where postStatus = 0, 
inactive = select count (postStatus) inactive where postStatus = 1,
recalled = select count (postStatus) recalled where postStatus = 5, 
deleted = select count (postStatus) deleted where postStatus = 6
from userData where userId = 1;
```

**Expected results**

```
"userId"    "published" "inactive"  "recalled"  "deleted"
"1"         "4"         "3"         "2"         "1"
```

In the end, it works out to select count from userData for userId = 1 and update userStats with that data for that user. Can you please help?

**Solution**

```
update userStats us
join (select
  userId,
  sum(postStatus = 0) published,
  sum(postStatus = 1) inactive,
  sum(postStatus = 5) recalled,
  sum(postStatus = 6) deleted
from userData where userId = 1) d on d.userId = us.userId set
us.published = d.published,
us.inactive = d.inactive,
us.recalled = d.recalled,
us.deleted = d.deleted;
```

Comment: Ok. But even then, is there a cleaner way to do this instead of using multiple select statements and wheres?

Comment: are you sure your sample data for `userdata` shouldn't all be userid = 1? your expected output suggests so.

Comment: You're correct. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this question makes sense is if all sample rows for `userData` are for userId 1, and that you want to update all users with their totals.

Firstly, here's the query for the data:

```
select
  userId,
  sum(postStatus = 0) published,
  sum(postStatus = 1) inactive,
  sum(postStatus = 5) recalled,
  sum(postStatus = 6) deleted
from userData
group by 1
```

Btw, the reason the totals work is that in mysql true is 1 and false is 0, so *summing* a condition counts how many times it's true! It makes the query very neat compared to long winded case statements.

Now to update another table, use mysql's special update-with-join syntax:

```
update userStats us
join (select
  userId,
  sum(postStatus = 0) published,
  sum(postStatus = 1) inactive,
  sum(postStatus = 5) recalled,
  sum(postStatus = 6) deleted
from userData
group by 1) d on d.userId = us.userId set
us.published = d.published,
us.inactive = d.inactive,
us.recalled = d.recalled,
us.deleted = d.deleted
where us.userId = 1 -- optional where clause. leave out to update all users
```

This will correctly update all users in one query.

This is quite efficient because it make one pass over the userData table (instead of 4 passes with separate subqueries) and *all* users have their stats refreshed (rather than separate queries for each user).

I you actually only want to update one particular user, just add a `where us.userId = ?` to the end of the query.

I would encourage you to consider using raw data rather than denormalizing the results into the userStats table, unless there's a very compelling reason. It's a form of caching, and caching comes with many hidden maintenance overheads and subtle problems.

Comment: I updated the question. There are other userId's in there too.

Comment: @Norman this updates all users at once: the join is made on userid

Comment: Actually, I need it for a particular `userId`, so where does the `where userId = 1` clause go? and secondly, you're missing commas, but I fixed that, but even then, the thing will not work. `published` is set to 1 that's all.

Comment: @Norman see updated answer. this should work. if only published is updated, maybe that's all the data there is?

Comment: Ah! You're `using group by 1`. I removed that and now it updateds like my expected results. But I hope that is the right way.

Comment: @norman no, it's not the right way. you need the group by for it to work properly. The best thing would be for you to create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with enough the sample data to cover edge cases, then you or I can try my query to make sure it's working properly

Comment: But with that, all that's updated is the published column with a value of 1. See my expected results, all the four need to be updated at once, and there a `4 published, 3 inactive, 2 recalled and 1 deleted posts for userId = 1`

Comment: Are you *positive* you have copied the query exactly? As in copy-paste? What does the select query give, when you add `where userId = 1` to it?

Comment: Ok I got it right this time. BTW, I think it's a good idea to use the where clause in the select itself. That gives you the data for only `userId = 1` rather that all the userIds. And I'm still wondering why you used group by 1 in there.

Comment: Yes, If you have `userId=1` inside the subquery, you don't need the group by or selecting or joining on userId, but surely you would want to update all users to set all their values to the latest wouldn't you? Without the where clause, you can update them all very quickly

Comment: Thanks. Not all `userIds` need to be updated at once. Only a user who's post is published or deleted or recalled or etc by the mod. This will be used in the mod section of the site. So if a mod deletes the post of a user, only that users data (count)needs to be updated. The other users data stays unchanged. That's the way it goes :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the sql i'm going to use. Hope that's the right thing. And remind me to give you both guys a few extra points after 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way using a `JOIN` with the `UPDATE` statement

```
update userStats  
join
(
select userId,
sum(case when postStatus = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as pub, 
sum(case when postStatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as inac,
sum(case when postStatus = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as recal,
sum(case when postStatus = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as del
from userData
) tab on userStats.userId = tab.userId
set published = tab.pub,
inactive = tab.inac,
recalled = tab.recal,
deleted = tab.del
where userStats.userId = 1
```

Comment: Hmm... Column 'published' in field list is ambiguous. It's actually not, and nothing gets updated.

Comment: That was because column names were same between userstats and derived table. try the edited query.

Comment: This one updates userStats published with a value of 10 which is the count of all rows in there :-)

Comment: Ah! yes that way count will not work, you can change it using sum instead of count.